# Mercurial Editor: "abort: The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: configuration, mercurial, editor, notepad++

I have a problem getting Mercurial to recognise my editor. I have a file, `c:\windows\notepad.exe` and typing "notepad" at the command prompt works. I can commit by using the "`-m`" argument to supply the commit title. But a simple "`hg commit`" brings up the error.

A call to "`hg --traceback commit`" brings up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 47, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 466, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 336, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 517, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 471, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 465, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 401, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 708, in commit
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyc", line 1150, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 706, in commitfunc
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyc", line 836, in commit
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyc", line 1155, in commiteditor
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyc", line 1184, in commitforceeditor
  File "mercurial\ui.pyc", line 361, in edit
  File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 383, in system
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 470, in call
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 621, in __init__
  File "subprocess.pyc", line 830, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
abort: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried setting the HGEDITOR environment variable, setting "`visual =`" and "`editor =`" in the `Mercurial.ini` file. I tried full path as well as command only. I also tried copying the notepad.exe file into both the current folder as well as the mercurial folder.

Ideally I would like to use the editor at this location "`C:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe`", but at this stage I would be happy with any editor!

HG debugconfig output:

```
c:\wamp\www\SiteAB.com\web>hg debugconfig
bundle.mainreporoot=c:\wamp\www\SiteAB.com\web
ui.username=killroy
ui.shell=true
ui.verbose=true
ui.visual="C:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe"
ui.editor="C:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe"
```

Comment: Are you using win7 64bit by any chance? I am getting a similar problem and started a report at https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/1361/cannot-successfully-run-merge-tools-on-win-7-64

Comment: I appear to have fixed my problem by reinstalling the OS. Extreme measures...

Comment: I guess that'll happen sooner or later! Still annoying though. But why can't it just execute the executable I give it?

Answer (score 5):

That `editor = notepad` didn't work suggests something is wrong with your environment.  Since running notepad from the command line works, I wonder if maybe the problem is with your python installation.  Your backtrace makes me think you're running hg 1.5 which was current when you posted.  While I don't believe it should make a difference, it couldn't hurt to update to 1.5.4.

You're running Notepad++Portable from your C: drive.  Usually one installs PortableApps to a removable drive.  Are you sure hg should look at C:?  I understand sometimes it can be handy for unpriviledged users to install them locally.  Notepad++Portable won't play particularly nice with hg.  You'll need to have npp completely closed and spawn it from hg or commits won't work.  If you can, I'd try running the full version of [Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/files/) instead.  Here's what I use:

```
[ui]
editor = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession
```

`-multiInst` tells npp to open a new instance just for hg.  That way it won't interfere with any npp windows you already have open.  This does not work with the PortableApps version.
`-nosession` tells npp not to open any files you previously had open, speeding startup times and reducing clutter.  When I'm writing a commit message, I want to focus on my message, and not be distracted by a bunch of unrelated tabs.

Comment: It's the correct path. I use PortableApps for ease of backup and transfer. Not to use from a memory stick. If you call the main executable (as I am), there is no multi-instance check or problem. I will try your params, though.

Comment: I used the above config, minus changing it to Program Files (x86) since I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.  Works perfectly, thanks.  I'll add that I followed a guide to "replace" notepad with notepad++, however this didn't work transparently for hg, probably because notepad++ uses a stub program in the windows directories to launch the main executable in response to opening "notepad.exe".

Answer (score 0):

When you set `editor =` in the Mercurial.ini file, you're doing it within the `[ui]` section, right?

After doing that maybe provide the output of `hg debugconfig` ?

Comment: I've added the output. But as I mentioned, I tried various different incantations, including a simple "editor = notepad", none of which work. It would be really useful to be able to see what command it is trying to execute to open the editor. Perhaps it's some sort of path-mangling issue?